# Use HtmlEncode in Details View TemplateItem Control

Tags: asp.net

I have details view control in my asp.net web form, which on of its item template gets it is value from database, and show this into a richtextbox :

```
<FTB:FreeTextBox id="txtDescription" runat="Server" AllowHtmlMode="false" Text='<%# (Eval("Description") )%>'
                >
                </FTB:FreeTextBox>
```

but when i click on insert or update button, i get the following error :

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client ....

i tried this :

```
Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)Eval("Description"))%>'
```

bu it did not work ethier, and i got the error again.
is there any way except turning validateRequest off.
Would you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to get this to work aside from turning Validate Request off.  Which isn't a bad thing if you write your database functionality correctly and implement strict custom form validation.

Comment: if i turn Validate Request off, can I still validate controls on my page?

Comment: yeah you can, it will only do what you are experiencing e.g. validate formvalues for possible malicious attacks on your website.

Comment: dear Peter, i tried HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)Eval("Description")) with Validate Request turned off, but my text was not saved in database.